# Edit theme login page

Tags: 7, users

I'm using a theme called [Nexus](https://www.drupal.org/project/nexus).

Now in the login page, /?q=user, it looks somewhat like this:
[image]

All I want to do is change the order of the tabs, where "Log in" is in front, number one, then Request new password, then lastly Create new account.

Aka:
[Log in][Request new password][Create new account]

I've tried looking in the theme's folder, including page.tpl.php, and in the user module files to see if I could find where it was defined/rendered but I couldn't find anything.
[This](https://www.drupal.org/node/350634) also did not seem to be what I wanted.

Sorry for being such a noob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [hook_menu_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) function to do it

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu_alter.
 */
 function MYMODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
   $items['user/login']['weight'] = 0;
   $items['user/password']['weight'] = 1;
   $items['user/register']['weight'] = 2;
 }
```

Comment: In sites/all/themes/Nexus/nexus/template.php, nexus_menu_alter(&$items) this is already defined ... in the same order. How come it does not render the same way?

Comment: have you cleared caches?

Comment: Tried clearing caches, tried changing weights and clearing cache again.

Comment: Sorry I've made mistake in code, now it should work

Comment: That's weird though, it was defined with '#weight' in the existing theme code, removing the '#' did nothing.. Cleared my caches too.